# Call a parent's method/property

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a custom class and I add it as child of a scene. In this custom class, I'd like to call a method or property found in the scene. So basically how can I call methods/properties from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CocosNode's `get_ancestor(self, klass)` routine to discover the objects that contain the node. If you specify the scene's class in the `klass` parameter, that routine should give you the object you're looking for.